# How to grab MainWindow instead of centralWidget?

Tags: qt, opengl, qpixmap, qopenglwidget

When I want to grab the whole window, I can only grab what is drawed with OpenGL in centralWidget.

```
QPixmap my_pixmap = QPixmap::grabWidget(ui->OpenGLWidget, 0, 0, frameto264.iWidth, frameto264.iHeigth);
```

What I have draw with QT, like QPixmap or QPainter(or even in statusBar), cant not be showed in grabWidget.

**Can anyone tell me how to grab the whole mainwindow, or was the *ui->OpenGLWidget* using wrong?**

It is my first time asking question on stackoverflow. If there is something wrong with my statement, please be free to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You are capturing the opengl only because that is what you are giving as parameter to the method grabWidget here:

```
QPixmap::grabWidget(ui->OpenGLWidget....
```

Instead of doing

```
grabWidget(ui->OpenGLWidget,...
```

repalce the pointer to your openGl widget by a pointer to the mainWindow

Comment: I changed the code :```QPixmap::grabWidget(this,....```   in the class mainwindow, but I still can not grab the whole mainwindow.  Plus, the screen I grabed turned into green.  Is there anything else I can do?  Or do I changed code wrong?